# C++20 Concept for Templated Method - non const lvalue reference cannot bind to rvalue

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts

I am trying to write a concept to require the given type to have a templated method, but am struggling to make the concept recognize that I have implemented the method correctly.

I have an interface and a basic implementation defined like this:

```
template <typename T>
class Other {
  public:
    virtual auto make() -> T = 0;
};

class Impl : public Other<int> {
  public:
    auto make() -> int {
        return 1;
    }
};
```

I want to make a concept that requires a given type has a templated method that can take an instance of `Other` and return the templated type that `Other` contains. That method looks like this:

```
class Thing {
  public:
    template <typename T>
    auto some(Other<T>& other) -> T {
        return other.make();
    }
};
```

I currently have written a concept that I thought would work as such:

```
template <typename T>
concept IsCorrect = requires (T v) {
    { v.template some(Impl{}) } -> std::same_as<int>;
};
```

But adding a static assert:

```
static_assert(IsCorrect<Thing>);
```

fails with:

```
<source>:29:15: error: static assertion failed
   29 | static_assert(IsCorrect<Thing>);
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:29:15: note: because 'Thing' does not satisfy 'IsCorrect'
<source>:19:18: note: because 'v.template some(Impl{})' would be invalid: no matching member function for call to 'some'
   19 |     { v.template some(Impl{}) } -> std::same_as<int>;
      |                  ^
1 error generated.
Compiler returned: 1
```

How can I fix the concept so that this passes?

Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/Y5eeTrado

Comment: `some` takes an lvalue, `Impl{}` is an rvalue. Just change it to this: https://godbolt.org/z/j886TdGr7

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work, do you want to add it as an answer?